# When triggered from SQS, AWS Lambda does not trigger SNS notifications on failure condition

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I created AWS Lambda and set that is trigged when some SQS message appears. Lambda is triggered and let's say that fails. I wanted to setup "On failure" destination which triggers SNS topic where I would have Email subscription.

I deliberately  made lambda fail, I can see failure in Cloudwatch. However, I didn't received any email from SNS.

To confirm everything actually works regarding SNS and Email subscription I setup S3 as additional trigger to lambda.
In this case, lambda is triggered, failed but I received email from SNS topic configured inside lambda. That means configuration is correct but something is different when source trigger for lambda is SQS rather than S3.

What I am missing? Why Lambda is not triggering SNS (or SNS not triggering notifications) when source for lambda is SQS and works perfectly when source is let's say S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda destinations onSuccess / onFailure are supported o[nly for asynch invocations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html): S3 calls your Lambda asynchronously, SQS calls it synchronously instead.

If you want to mantain the current implementation, you have to put the SNS publish directly inside your Lambda.

Comment: Do you maybe have link? It is not really easy to see inside AWS web? I don't know why  AWS does not provide better UX in this regard

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what link do you need... if you need how to push a message in an SNS from Lambda, just search google, there are tons of examples.

Comment: I meant about official documentation where that information is provided. I didn't noticed anywhere. It is especially strange since AWS allows to create "OnFailure" event for lambda even tough source is SQS. Anyway, I implemeted sending SNS from lambda in 20 minutes, that is easy. What is hard is the fact that AWS has some strange edge cases which are hard to debug and figure out.

Comment: In my answer there's the link of the official documentation where is stated that destionations are a feature only for asynch invocations. The reason I guess is simple: a success / failure destination of synchronous invocation is the caller itself. If you need more control over your flow, you should do it manually, or using Step Functions. I don't see it as an "edge case": is a linear behavior, knowing the architecture of Lambdas.